# FileName Port is not supported with connection or merge option

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to create a csv flat file and need to store in particular path in ftp .

File name should be dynmaically created with timestamp . i have created the filename port in informatica and mapped to expression which i created. when i ran the workflow , am getting below error

Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
ERROR   28-06-2017 07:31:19 PM  node01_oktst93  WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8419    Flat File Target [NewOrders] FileName Port is not supported with connection or merge option.

Please help to resolve without deleting filename port .

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't https://kb.informatica.com/solution/11/Pages/102937.aspx answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to create dynamic file during each session run. Please check the below steps:

1) Connect the source qualifier to an expression transformation. In the expression transformation create an output port (call it as File_Name) and assign the expression as 'FileNameXXX'||to_char(sessstarttime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'.csv'

2) Now connect the expression transformation to the target and connect eh File_Name port of expression transformation to the FileName port of the target file definition.

3) Create a workflow and run the workflow.

I have used `sessstarttime`, as it is constant throughout the session run. If you have used `sysdate`, a new file will be created whenever a new transaction occurs in the session run

Answer (score 0):

file port option dosen't work with the FTP target option. If you are simply using a local flat file: please disable the append if exists option at session level.

Please refer the below informatica KB :

https://kb.informatica.com/solution/11/Pages/102937.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but may help some.

> Since file port option dosen't work with the FTP target option.
>   Another way is to

Create a variable in workflow

[image]

Then create an assignment in between

Then you may set the $variable with full path i.e.

```
'/path/to_drop/file/name_of_file_'||to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')||'.csv'
```

[image]

Use that $variable now in your session under workflows.

add it in your mappings now

[image]

Late answer but may help some.